# Informal ways to make a proposition?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to know informal ways (both American and British English) to propose a plan (e.g. going to a party, doing something interesting, starting a mutual job). This is **not** an offer for sex **at all** ( Please edit the post if "making proposition" usually means so). These are some of the sentences I though of:

> I wanna make you a proposition.

> I have a proposal for you.

> I have a plan.

Comment: "wanna" is informal, not standard. It's not something to use in formal writing or speech.

Comment: @Tristan Yes! I'm talking about **the informal**.

Comment: Let me [just put this to you](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22just+put+this+to+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). [What would you say to the idea that](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what+would+you+say+to+the+idea+that%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) the question is simply **Too Broad?** There are far too many possibilities, none of which would be appropriate in ***every*** context.

Comment: There may not be anything wrong with "I have a proposition for you," either. Remember, when it comes to very light innuendo, unintended sexual overtones depend not just on the words, but on the situation. My boss might say to me (male to male), "I have a proposition for you" and he need not worry about any unintended innuendo. If he's talking with a woman instead, he might choose his language more carefully, and say "I have an idea" instead.

Comment: Even when you're writing informal English, I recommend staying away from *wanna*.  Using *want to* always works, but *wanna* isn't always grammatical or natural in the same positions.  (This is just my personal advice and not a rule you need to follow, of course.)

Comment: @snailboat It seems that using _wanna_ is an habit of people who speak English as second language, as if using it would make them closer to native speakers. The problem is that they use it even when an English native speaker would not use it. `:)`

Comment: How about "I've got this plan". Proposal and proposition are slightly formal words. Maybe alternatives such as plan, suggestion or idea sound better. Using "this" make it clear you have a specific plan in mind, while "a plan" is more vague, like any old plan I found lying around. Definitely never use wanna - for the same reason @kiamlaluno says. I remember, in Blackadder, Baldrick often saying "I have a cunning plan", but I can't imagine him saying "I have a cunning proposition"

Answer (score 2):

To "proposition someone" is a rather informal (since it's really a noun) way of saying "to ask someone for sex."  *Proposal* isn't used in this way.  Also, to "propose to someone" means to ask someone to marry you.  *Make a proposition to someone* is the same as *proposing something to someone*.  *Plan* is different; it isn't really asking someone to do anything.